# How to have decreasing running total in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, cumulative-sum

I have a column with below values

```
Week    Value
0       83
1       0
2       1
3       4
4       0
5       9
```

I need the result as

```
Week    Value    Remaining
    0       83    83
    1       0     83
    2       1     82
    3       4     78
    4       0     78
    5       9     69
```

How to do this in Oracle SQL query. I know that I can achieve this in PL/SQL, but I want to achieve this in select query. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with cumulative sums:

```
select t.*,
       (max(case when week = 0 then value end) over () -
        coalesce(sum(case when week > 0 then value end) over (order by week), 0)
       ) as remaining
from t;
```

I don't think you should be treating week 0 as something special.  Instead, use positive and negative values.  Then you could just do:

```
select t.*,
       sum(value) over (order by week) as remaining
from t;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the values are not positive and negative.. and sum(value) over week will give increasing running total.

Comment: I have added one more scenario to the same query above. Any idea on the solution for the same?

Comment: @bharath . . . You should ask a new question.